# Recompensa maior que reputação

Tags: suporte, recompensa

Estava olhando as perguntas em [destaque](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=featured) e me deparei com [essa](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/156773/51124), onde a recompensa oferecida é maior que a reputação.

Nesse caso: "Roberval Sena 山本 oferece, até em 7 dias, uma recompensa de +150 pontos nessa pergunta". Sendo que a reputação dele é 25.

[O que é uma recompensa? Como ofereço uma?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/bounty), fala: 
"A gratificação é uma concessão especial de reputação oferecida às respostas. Ela é custeada pela reputação pessoal do usuário que a oferece e não é reembolsável."

Minha dúvida: o que acontece com a reputação do usuário que oferece uma recompensa maior que a mesma?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A pontuação aplicada pelo recompensador é deduzida de sua reputação no momento em que ela é oferecida e não ao fim do período de destaque da pergunta.

Como se pode ver na [aba da reputação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/30243/roberval-sena-%E5%B1%B1%E6%9C%AC?tab=reputation) dela:

> [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ou seja, ela tinha 175 pontos antes de ofertar a recompensa, agora está com 25 apenas.

Comment: Agora faz sentido, não sabia que era assim. Achava que os pontos eram retirados depois que passasse o dia da recompensa. Obrigada =)

Comment: @Taisbevalle sem problemas ;-)